# python requests json from url

Tags: python, json, python-requests

### I am using python to scrape a url such as in the code blow

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

n_index = 10
base_link = 'http://xxx.xxx./getinfo?range=10&district_id=1&index='
for i in range (1,n_index+1):
    link = base_link+str(i)
    r = requests.get(link)
    pid = r.json()
    print (pid)
```

it's return ten result just like this blow

```
{'product_info': [{'pid': '1', 'product_type': '2'}]}
{'product_info': [{'pid': '2', 'product_type': '2'}]}
{'product_info': [{'pid': '3', 'product_type': '2'}]}
{'product_info': [{'pid': '4', 'product_type': '2'}]}
{'product_info': [{'pid': '5', 'product_type': '2'}]}
{'product_info': [{'pid': '6', 'product_type': '2'}]}
{'product_info': [{'pid': '7', 'product_type': '2'}]}
{'product_info': [{'pid': '8', 'product_type': '2'}]}
{'product_info': [{'pid': '9', 'product_type': '2'}]}
{'product_info': [{'pid': '10', 'product_type': '2'}]}
```

and then i want to save the resulting 10 lines into a json file, as presented in the code below:

```
with open('sylist.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(r.json(), outfile, indent=4)
```

but only one result is saved into the json file local, who can help me to resolve,thanks a lot

Comment: Use append instead of write ::-  `with open('sylist.json', 'a') as outfile:`

Answer (score 2):

On a typical way, try below way to write result line by line without open/close file at each time.

```
with open('sylist.json', 'a+') as outfile:
    for i in range (1,n_index+1):
        link = base_link+str(i)
        r = requests.get(link)
        outfile.write("{}\n".format(json.dump(r.json(), outfile, indent=4)))
```

Comment: @slackware hey, if it worked for you, please accept it:)

Answer (score 0):

Let me extend Frank's answer a bit.
You are sending the request inside the for loop, which means at every iteration of the loop, the value of **pid** is overwritten. As a result, when you want to dump its content to an output file, **pid** holds only the contents from the very last iteration/request. I would suggest to apply one of the following to address your issue:

1. Include writing component inside the for loop (or vice-versa, as suggested in the answer by Frank AK).
2. Instead of overwriting the content of **pid** each time, you may append it directly inside the for loop as follows:

   ```
   my_list = []
   for i in range (1,n_index+1):
       link = base_link+str(i)
       r = requests.get(link)
       pid = r.json()
       my_list.append(pid)

   with open('sylist.json', 'w') as outfile:
       json.dump(my_list, outfile, indent=4)
   ```